# Is there any way to generate a random permutation of integers without storing an array?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

For context, I am trying to create a feed of random users for an app I'm making, and I would like this to be a non-repeating feed (until of course you visit every user's profile). Suppose I have some users, indexed from 0 to X (so X+1 users, we disregard the user logged in). One way of going about this is creating an array and then applying the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to obtain a random permutation, and then sticking with that permutation.

However, my requirements are a little different. I'd like to generate a seed on the client-side and avoid having to generate an array like this, so the only data I send from my client is for pagination: `(offset, limit, seed)`.

It is, at its core, a random bijective mapping between the ranges `[0, X]` and `[0, X]`. Fundamentally this is a random permutation, but this comes with the overhead of storing the entire array. If I have 1 million entries it doesn't make sense to have to generate this array just to reach an arbitrary index.

In essence, is there a function which I can feed in an **offset** (x), **limit** (y), and **seed** such that it is able to compute the integer at position **x** in this random sequence of unique integers (which can be reproduced given the seed) between 0 and DB_SIZE (`0 <= x <=  DB_SIZE`), and then computes the **y** integers appearing after it? This should be done in O(1) time and space and without having the compute the **x-1** integers that come before **x** in this sequence. (Edit: *limit* here is the number of elements to retrieve after index **x**, inclusive. So if I want to grab the next 10 users, I would return, in traditional pagination, items at indices `x, x + 1, ... , x + 9`. Now these should be mapping to a random sequence of indices, say `[29, 57, 61, 1, 5, 30, 11, 70, 94, 7]`.

Is there any way for me to accomplish this?

Sidenote: Yes, after a user browses through 100 other users it is unlikely that the user would notice a repeat in the first place, so I could theoretically just ensure I have 100 unique users instead and then generate another 100 after this is exhausted (which may contain repeats from the previous 100, or however many before). That is an implementation I might have to fall back on, but I was wondering if this is remotely possible.

Comment: One such function is `f(x, y, seed) -> (x + seed) % y`. I think this isn't a programming question but a mathematical question in the field of numbers theory.

Comment: AFAIK for a prime number `y` the function `f(x, y, seed) -> x * seed % y` should also work but you have to check it first. Maybe there are requirements for `seed`, too. I don't remember.

Comment: Fwiw, imho, let's go [quantum](https://qrng.anu.edu.au/). Afaik, my best knowledge of non repeating random seed, is the 1 that is used for wolfram question generator (never generates the same question twice). But I don't have the algo. Quantum PC on the other hand.. hands the "nature" as the seed.. everytime..

Comment: I don't think that strong randomness is a requirement for this question. Math.random should be fine for this.

Comment: @CharlesBamford How do you calculate the 1000th random without generating 1000 random numbers (in O(1) operations)?

Comment: Math.random is fine for seed generation. You've got the correct solution in your comments. Quantum pc is overkill for seed generation.

Comment: @CharlesBamford Does `Math.random` allow to directly generate the 1000th number? Let's say you get a `seed` and an `x`. How do you calculate the random number and how do you guarantee that there are no duplicates?

Comment: Obviously this is not possible with random sequences. But since there is no real randomness in software you just need a pseudo-random number generator that generates unique values and can be reverted in a simple way or you can create your own pseudo-random number generator. What are your requirements for the pseudo-random number generator? Is `f(x, y, seed) -> x + seed % y` sufficient?

Comment: @jabaa I might be misinterpreting it, but wouldn't that proposed function still result in the same *order* of items, just at different starting indices based on the seed? And strong randomness is not a requirement, I can use `Math.random()` for the seed.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. There are so many [random permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation) that you would need to make your seed as large as the fisher-yates array would have been otherwise, to be able to generate all possible permutations.

Comment: Would a function like `f(x, y, seed) -> (123456789 * x * seed) % y` work for you? This would probably change the order. (It's just an example. You would have to calculcate the number `123456789` from `x`, `y` and `seed`).

Comment: No, the order gets shuffled, but it is cyclical.

Comment: @jabaa Pardon if I am misunderstanding this, but I'm not quite sure I see how this works. I don't think the offset (y) should even be factored into the calculation. With standard pagination you would request (for example) indices 50 - 59, so `x = 50` and `y = 10`. Suppose DB_SIZE = 100. Based on the seed, this could map to the indices `[29, 57, 61, 1, 5, 30, 11, 70, 94, 7]` (some reproducible random order due to the seed). If this were the result of a seeded Fisher-Yates shuffle (for example), these indices would be the values of the elements at indices 50 - 59 in the shuffled array. (1/2)

Comment: Since in this scenario we would just increment `x` by 1 until it hits the offset, so `(num * (x + 1) * seed)  % y` , so on and so forth, wouldn't that result in the same order still? (2/2)

Comment: An interesting question.  I'm curious if  you've tried calculating the indices from a F-Y shuffle and found it too slow?  `O(n)` random operations for a request doesn't seem horrible, but I know nothing of your requirements.  And of course you wouldn't have to calculate further ones after they stop making requests.

Comment: @ScottSauyet The Fisher-Yates shuffle would definitely work but why I can't use that method is because what is displayed on each client should be randomized and I can't afford the extra space. I don't think it makes sense from a design perspective to shuffle an entire array of ~1m or more integers on the client-end and then paginate through them by sending each requested chunk of indices. (This also exposes the exact user count to end users which I don't think is ideal). I can't do this on the server either because I need to then remember the exact shuffled array for each user visiting (1/2)

Comment: this page. Even with a seeded Fisher-Yates shuffle, if my server doesn't store the result for every user active on that page, I then need to recompute this for every request. The ideal option is if I can find such a function as outlined in the question. I've read up a little on [Linear Feedback Shift Registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register) but I'm not too sure if/how it could apply to my use case. (2/2)

Comment: I was not suggesting a full F-Y shuffle, but only running as much as you need to (using a seeded random generator) in order to calculate the `n` elements needed.  (You can always stop the shuffle after you're found the first `n` elements.)  If you're talking about real users, I would be surprised if they would be hitting the 10,000th page.  I am thinking about another approach, but probably won't be able to try it before tomorrow.

Comment: @ScottSauyet You have actually brought up a fantastic point. I could run the first `n` iterations of the F-Y shuffle on the client, and then I just need to send the indices over the wire. When the user scrolls to a certain point, I can compute the next required iterations (though I _think_ this would require starting the shuffle at index 0 with the same seed?). The only drawbacks I see are that this exposes the exact user count to end users, though there may be some smart ways to hide/obfuscate it, but the bigger drawback would be that the client needs to store an (1/2)

Comment: array of `x` integers (number of users, so 1m users would mean there'd still be this 1m-sized array in memory), unless there's a way to bypass that too? Would love to hear about your other approach too once you have the time. (2/2)

Comment: I've never tried, but I think you could do F-Y on a sparse array, using the value if it's there and the index otherwise, but it would definitely require knowing the length.  Is the number of users actually secret information?  That would be surprising since it would be derivable from any implementation of this idea -- when you hit the same item again, you've cycled through and you know the length.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I wouldn't say it's secret per se but I'm not sure about that from a best practices point of view. But it's a minor thing in my opinion and I'm more than happy to accept that as a compromise in the name of an elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

As jabaa said in the comments, all you need is a seed. The seed should be a large prime number.

```js
// Potential seeds. These aren't very large, nor are there enough of them.
const seeds = [1299631, 1299637, 1299647, 1299653, 1299673, 1299689];
const seed = seeds[Math.floor(Math.random() * seeds.length)];

function getUserAtN(offset, limit, seed) {
  return ((offset + 1) * seed) % limit;
}

function getListOfUsers(numberOfUsers, listLength) {
  return Array(listLength).fill(0).map((_, i) => getUserAtN(i, numberOfUsers, seed));
}

console.log("The list is shuffled.", getListOfUsers(10, 20));

console.log("A user can be reliably found.", getUserAtN(3, 10, seed));
```

Comment: The question clearly states: _"This should be done in O(1) time and space and without having the compute the x-1 integers that come before x in this sequence."_ `Array(listLength)` is not O(1)..

Comment: I was demonstrating that the solution *you proposed* creates a shuffled list. Of course the id at any index can be found.

Comment: The questions is how a new user can calculate a new unique pseudo-random number in O(1) time and memory complexity and this answer doesn't solve the problem (or I don't understand it).

Comment: I don't think that's it. It looks like a gallery with items in a shuffled order.

Comment: it's O(1), forget `getListOfUsers` that's just a demo, just read the `getUserAtN` bit and all will make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You should use format-preserving encryption (fpe). There are implementations in Javascript available.

With fpe you can bijectice relate an integer interval with a given seed.

Comment: Can you explain how that helps?  I read a little about fpe and don't see the connection.